# using a shared database between eclipse and asp.NET C#

Tags: android, asp.net, database, eclipse

I have an android application in eclipse and it works in parallel with a website.
i.e both are use the same database. I get headache to decide what type of database to be used in both.
I don't want to use a web service and the SQL Server 2005 database.

Could you please guide me to a better king of database to be used by both (the Android app and the asp.NET website)?

Thanks..

Comment: I think the best answer would really be: `use a web service and the SQL Server`

Comment: question: You don't want to use a SQL Server 2005 Database??
But what are you going to use for your ASP.Net Web Service?
I mean by database?

Comment: @MDMalik No Thanks. I am going to use SQL Server 2005 Database in my website. But I meant that  I don't want to use web service. I think there is no way better than that..

Comment: @user3287580 I guess u never made a web service. Hence a bit confused. Went down the same road